# How to make additional database-level validation in SQL Server LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project. The user can create an appointment by filling out a form and selecting an unoccupied date and time for the meeting. In the `Create` action, I have one more check:

```
if (db.Orders.Where(o => o.Time == order.Time).Count() > 0)
    ModelState.AddModelError("Time", "Selected time is occupied");
```

What if two requests with equal `Time` values get to the server simultaneously? I think, there should be database-level validation and if so, how to perform it?

Comment: Add a [Unique Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints)

Comment: you probably only want to check hour and minute not entire time as including seconds milliseconds etc